# PHP Undefined variable error when calling the result of query

Tags: php, function

Working on my first PHP blog system, I cannot display the result of my query from the page
**articles.php**

```
include ('config/dbconnect.php');
function selectArticleById( $IdArticle, $c ){

$sqlArticlesId = 'SELECT 
            artID,
            artTitre,
            artAuteur,
            artContenu,
            artDate
            FROM articles
            WHERE artID =\''.$IdArticle.'\'
            ';
$result = mysqli_query($c, $sqlArticlesId); 
return $result;
```

}

Calling this function in my
 **menu.inc.php**

```
<?php 

$rArticlesId = selectArticleById( $row['artID'], $conn ); ?>
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rArticlesId)){ ?> 

<ul class="menu">

<li><a href="index.php?page=articleform"><?php echo $row['artTitre']; ?></a></li>
<?php echo $row['artTitre']; ?>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
```

I get the error : undefined variable **row** in.
SQL injections will be dealt accordingly.  I just would like to understand how the function works with 2 variables.

Comment: where does $row['artID'] come from..?

Answer (score 4):

The `$row` in the below line is undefined.

```
$rArticlesId = selectArticleById( $row['artID'], $conn ); ?>
```

Maybe you mean `$_GET['artID']` ?

```
$rArticlesId = selectArticleById( $_GET['artID'], $conn ); ?>
```

Comment: @swissed if you can see your code and let us know from where you are getting $_GET['artID']. it will be easy to debug

Answer (score 0):

you are using $row in this line `$rArticlesId = selectArticleById( $row['artID'], $conn ); ?>`

while $row is created in the line below

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rArticlesId)){ ?>
```

You need to use the correct variable here.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all who helped me out. Answering my own question:
  I declared **row** within menu.inc.php:

```
<?php 
$rows =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($rArticles); //THIS IS WHAT I ADDED
$rArticlesId = selectArticleById( $rows['artID'], $conn ); ?>
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rArticlesId)){ ?> 

 <ul class="menu">

<li><a href="index.php?page=articleform"><?php echo $row['artTitre']; ?></a></li>
<?php echo $row['artTitre']; ?>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
```